# stream reader c# taking off leading 0

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, sql-server-2008, streamreader

I am using stream reader (ASP.NET C# 4.0) to read an XML file. However when i am importing the data to store in my MS SQL 2008 R2 Database it is taking off the leading 0 from an amazon item ID i am using.

For example the amazonitemid is stored in the XML file as - 00567416803507. However when it is moved to the DB via stream reader it removed the 2 0's- 567416803507 . This also happens if there is just 1 leading 0.

I have looked around for any solutions but cant seem to find anything that is of use. Does any one know any way around this, or even why this is happening?

Comment: Can you post your code regarding the stream reader?

Comment: Do you convert the ID to a number? Numbers have no concept of leading zeros.

Comment: All sorted now, seems it was an issue with the amazon class lib. Thanks for the responses!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Treat the ID as a string, not a number.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you step in to the code to see where it is really getting truncated.

If the application side of it is passing the value correctly, I would look at the database side of it; the stored proc/ query & the table column type.